# CSS Question: What has precendence?

Tags: css

I am not new to CSS, I'm just not that adept with it.  I ran into an 'issue' today in having a sub-element being overwritten by the parent's css.   After some head scratching I realized all I needed to do was add an '! important' to the css (which to show you my ability is brand new to me)

(I have placed a working example @ that illustrates my question in living color)
http://jsfiddle.net/4RYM3/1/

```
#byIdName div{  /* #1 */
       margin: 30px;
    background:#FF00FF;
}
div#ByIdNameTwo{  /* #2 */
           margin: 30px;
     background:#00FF00;
}
div.idone{
    margin: 20px;
    background:#FFFF00;
}
div.idtwo{
    margin: 0px;
    background:#cccccc;
}
div.idone2{
    margin: 20px ! important;
    background:#FFFF00 ! important;
}
div.idtwo2{
    margin: 0px ! important;
    background:#cccccc ! important;
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Now looking at this, I cannot understand why #1 and #2 seem to behave differently (please look at the jsfiddle link above).
While I am happy that I got this to work (with the **! Important**) I am lost as to the *why* #1 and #2 are behaving in the manner that they are.

Can anyone shed some light on this behavior?

Is one the preferred method and the other looked down upon, and if so why (this is my main question)?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These behave differently because `#byIdName div` refers to any children of type div with parent #byIdName

This `div#ByIdNameTwo` refers to any div with ID `#byIdNameTwo`

for Direct children use `#byIdName>div`

for any children including grand-children great-grand-children....etc.   use

```
#byIdName div
```

Comment: okay, so they are not the same, but for children shouldn't there be a ">"? (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) -- this level of css is new to me so I hope my question isn't too noob

Comment: The `>` implies that the child inherits properties from the parent.

Comment: got it!  (didn't read far enough up) http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The !important rule is a way to make your CSS cascade but also have the rules you feel are most crucial always be applied.

Though this works differently based on browser-specific implementation.

More info here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm

Answer (score 1):

hey taning,  this is a little hard to explain, but here's my try:

in general, the more specific selector will override the more general one.
**ids** are meant to be **very specific** (one per page),
**classes** are more **general** (as many as you want per page).

so when you use `#byIdName div`, it overrides the class '.idtwo' for any divs inside an element with the id '#byIdName', since the declaration starting with the id is more specific.

in the second case, `div#ByIdNameTwo` refers only to a div with that id, not affecting child divs.

i hope that explains it.

-also, i highly recommend that you avoid the !important rule, as it is poison for maintaining code later (and it shows that the programmer doesn't really understand cascading rules).  I don't mean this as a personal offence, i used to love `!important` myself, but its hacky and better avoided.

Comment: I think in this case the use of ! important definitely shows that the programmer doesn't really understand cascading rules; but I will take your advise to heart.

Comment: hey we all start out not understanding, you should see my javascript. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#byIdName div{  /* #1 */
       margin: 30px;
    background:#FF00FF;
}
```

This block of code targets only divs that are INSIDE of the element with the "byIdName" attribute.

```
div#ByIdNameTwo{  /* #2 */
           margin: 30px;
     background:#00FF00;
}
```

This block of code targets only a div element that has the id "ByIdNameTwo". If it is not a div with that ID, it will be ignored.

Also, the ID selector will override the class selector because it is more specific. Adding "!important" will fix that, but it's not recommended. Using "!important" is not a practice that should be encouraged when there are better alternates.

The better solution would be something like this:

```
#ByIdNameTwo.idone2 {
  margin: 20px;
  background: #FFFF00;
}
```

As an additional note, try to avoid using unnecessary elements in your css selectors (such as "div" in these cases). It actually takes the CSS selector engine longer to find match these types of rules than just using the ID or class name.